# Why does iOS file management inconsistently use strings (paths) and URLs?

Tags: ios, nsfilemanager

So while working with file manager, I keep running into methods that only take URLs (such as building directories) and other methods that only take strings (such as removing files).

Why didn't NSFileManager standardize on one or the other?  What is the point of inconsistently using one or the other depending on the method being used?

Comment: Yes, there are path based methods for removing files (because, as observed below, this was how we used to do it), but there are now [URL methods for removing files](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsfilemanager/1413590-removeitematurl?language=objc), too, which you should use nowadays, unless you’re supporting OS version that predates the URL renditions.

Comment: I think this is a fair question, and is not opinion-based. The reasons for the string-based and URL-based file system commands is historic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a question of history. The older methods worked with paths. Over time, Apple has migrated to URL-based methods. Some of the newer functions only support URLs.

In fact, in Mac OS, with it's funky form of sandboxing where apps are not allowed access to directories unless the user selects them, you *HAVE* to use URL-based methods since the URLs have embedded user permission information that the string-based methods lack.